# Why was my launcher setup reset after inserting a SIM card?

Tags: settings, sim-card, launcher, android-12, oppo-coloros

I have a new phone, and I started to "customize" it while still using my old one.
When I felt the phone is ready for switch-over, I inserted the SIM card from the old phone.

That worked, but after opening the MMS sent by the provider, it caused some app to be installed without my explicit consent.
A moment later I realized that my launcher configuration was reset to default:
All my icons and folders that I had placed and created before were gone!

- Is that usual for Android 12 (Oppo's "Color OS" 12.1), or is it unusual?
- Is there any chance to get my setup of the launcher back?

I was thinking whether removing the SIM card again would restore my launcher, but then I though:
Better ask here!

Comment: That a manufacturer installs additional bloatware apps based on the customer country is nothing new. I wasn't aware that for the country detection the SIM may be used. Unfortunately I don't see any chance that removing the SIM card will revert the changes. Android does not provide a way to save app data in a way that would later allow to go back to that state. All changes are permanent.

Comment: So installation of the provider's app did the layout reset? I had uninstalled that apps in the meantime as I don't need them. Also my phone knew the region I live in before inserting the SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, the provider's "Welcome" app installed itself as "launcher" without Android asking me for permissions to do so (how did they manage that?).
Also it did not just reset the start screen, but also changed some display options regarding that status bar.